# Dynamic table view using html and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, mysql

I have one table in MySQL which looks like below:

```
+-----------------+------------------+-------------+------------+--------------+-------------+------------+--------------+-------------+------------+--------------+--------------+-------------+---------------+--------------+-------------+---------------+--------------+-------------+---------------+
| total_marks_phy | total_marks_chem | s_name_phy1 | s_add_phy1 | s_marks_phy1 | s_name_phy2 | s_add_phy2 | s_marks_phy2 | s_name_phy3 | s_add_phy3 | s_marks_phy3 | s_name_chem1 | s_add_chem1 | s_marks_chem1 | s_name_chem2 | s_add_chem2 | s_marks_chem2 | s_name_chem3 | s_add_chem3 | s_marks_chem3 |
+-----------------+------------------+-------------+------------+--------------+-------------+------------+--------------+-------------+------------+--------------+--------------+-------------+---------------+--------------+-------------+---------------+--------------+-------------+---------------+
| 98              | 142              | a           | colony1    | 98           |             |            |              |             |            |              | b            | colony2     | 72            | c            | colony3     | 70            |              |             |               |
+-----------------+------------------+-------------+------------+--------------+-------------+------------+--------------+-------------+------------+--------------+--------------+-------------+---------------+--------------+-------------+---------------+--------------+-------------+---------------+
```

Now I want to display it in one table in a jsp page and my jsp page looks like below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert Title Here</title>
<style>
input[type=text]{
    box-sizing:transparent;
    border:none;
    font-size:14pt;
    background-color:#0059b3;
    text-shadow:3px 3px 3px #000000;
    font-style:verdana;
    color:white;
}
</style></head>
<body background="images\download4.jpg">
<%
    classroom cr1 = (classroom)session.getAttribute("cr1");
    if(cr1 != null){
%>
<font face="Verdana" size=4 color="white">
    <table border="1" align="center">
        <tr bgcolor="#00004d">
            <th>Class Name</th>
            <th>Total<br>Marks</th>
            <th>Name of<br>the Student</th>
            <th>Individual<br>Marks</th></tr>
        <tr bgcolor="#0059b3" style="text-shadow:3px 3px 3px #000000">
            <td><u>Physics</u></td>
            <td><%=cr1.getTMarksP() %></td>
            <td><%=cr1.getNameSP1()%> (<%=cr1.getAddP1() %>)</td>
            <td><%=cr1.getMarksP1() %></td></tr>
        <tr bgcolor="#0059b3" style="text-shadow:3px 3px 3px #000000">
            <td><input type="text" id="1" style="display:none;"></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="2" style="display:none;"></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="3" style="dispaly:none;" value="<%=cr1.getNameSP2()%> (<%=cr1.getAddP2() %>)"></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="4" style="dispaly:none;" value="<%=cr1.getMarksP2() %>"></td></tr>
        <tr bgcolor="#0059b3" style="text-shadow:3px 3px 3px #000000" style="display:none;">
            <td><input type="text" id="5" style="dispaly:none;"></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="6" style="dispaly:none;"></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="7" style="dispaly:none;" value="<%=cr1.getNameSP3()%> (<%=cr1.getAddP3() %>)"></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="8" style="dispaly:none;" value="<%=cr1.getMarksP3() %>"></td></tr>
        <tr bgcolor="#0059b3" style="text-shadow:3px 3px 3px #000000">
            <td><u>Chemistry</u></td>
            <td><%=cr1.getTMarksC() %></td>
            <td><%=cr1.getNameSC1()%> (<%=cr1.getAddC1 %>)</td>
            <td><%=cr1.getMarksC1() %></td></tr>
        <tr bgcolor="#0059b3" style="text-shadow:3px 3px 3px #000000">
            <td><input type="text" id="9" style="display:none;"></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="10" style="display:none;"></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="11" style="display:none;" value="<%=cr1.getNameSC2()%> (<%=cr1.getAddC2%>)"></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="12" style="display:none;" value="<%=cr1.getMarksC2() %>"></td></tr>
        <tr bgcolor="#0059b3" style="text-shadow:3px 3px 3px #000000">
            <td><input type="text" id="13" style="display:none;"></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="14" style="display:none;"></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="15" style="display:none;" value="<%=cr1.getNameSC3()%> (<%=cr1.getAddC3%>)"></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="16" style="display:none;" value="<%=cr1.getMarksC3() %>"></td></tr>
    </table></font> 
<%
}
%>
<script>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',_ => {
    const a1=document.getElementById('1');
    const a2=document.getElementById('2');
    const a3=document.getElementById('3');
    const a4=document.getElementById('4');
    a1.style.display=a1.value && a1.value !== '' ? 'block' : 'none';
    a2.style.display=a2.value && a2.value !== '' ? 'block' : 'none';
    a3.style.display=a3.value && a3.value !== ' ()' ? 'block' : 'none';
    a4.style.display=a4.value && a4.value !== '' ? 'block' : 'none';
});
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',_ => {
    const b1=document.getElementById('5');
    const b2=document.getElementById('6');
    const b3=document.getElementById('7');
    const b4=document.getElementById('8');
    b1.style.display=b1.value && b1.value !== '' ? 'block' : 'none';
    b2.style.display=b2.value && b2.value !== '' ? 'block' : 'none';
    b3.style.display=b3.value && b3.value !== ' ()' ? 'block' : 'none';
    b4.style.display=b4.value && b4.value !== '' ? 'block' : 'none';
});
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',_ => {
    const c1=document.getElementById('9');
    const c2=document.getElementById('10');
    const c3=document.getElementById('11');
    const c4=document.getElementById('12');
    c1.style.display=c1.value && c1.value !== '' ? 'block' : 'none';
    c2.style.display=c2.value && c2.value !== '' ? 'block' : 'none';
    c3.style.display=c3.value && c3.value !== ' ()' ? 'block' : 'none';
    c4.style.display=c4.value && c4.value !== '' ? 'block' : 'none';
});
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',_ => {
    const d1=document.getElementById('13');
    const d2=document.getElementById('14');
    const d3=document.getElementById('15');
    const d4=document.getElementById('16');
    d1.style.display=d1.value && d1.value !== '' ? 'block' : 'none';
    d2.style.display=d2.value && d2.value !== '' ? 'block' : 'none';
    d3.style.display=d3.value && d3.value !== ' ()' ? 'block' : 'none';
    d4.style.display=d4.value && d4.value !== '' ? 'block' : 'none';
});
</script></body></html>
```

The above code works fine for me but the problem is that when the row contains 'NULL' value then I want only first and fourth row will be visible in the above jsp page. And also if there is nothing or 'NULL' value then the blank rows will also become invisible.

I have been tried this code since last two weeks but unable to solve this problem. Please help.

Comment: If it was me, I'd start over, with an appropriately designed schema. A database table is NOT a spreadsheet.

Comment: As @Strawberry points out, i think the problem resides way before the visualization of your table. By the look of things, you should normalize your database first

Comment: Strongly suggest that you sort out the structure in your server-side code (particularly the actual SQL query), rather than relying on client-side JS

Answer (score 0):

While not attempting a definitive solution, a normalised table might look something like this...

```
       s_name subject module mark add
       a      phy          1   98 Colony1
       b      chem         1   72 Colony2
       c      chem         2   70 Colony3
```